# How to vertically align label and input in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to vertically align label and input in Bootstrap 3?  I would like both the label and input on same line.  I have played around with different classes and custom CSS but nothing seems to work.

[The JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fatfantasma/mNPf9/)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="class_type"><h2><span class=" label label-primary">Class Type</span></h2></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <select name="class_type" id="class_type" class="  form-control input-lg" style="width:200px" autocomplete="off">
                <option >Economy</option>
                <option >Premium Economy</option>
                <option >Club World</option>
                <option >First Class</option>
            </select>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your `<label>` is inside of an `<h2>` tag, and header tags have a `margin` set by the default stylesheet.

Comment: How would I go about removing that margin if possible?

Comment: Ok, Just learning this stuff.  I modified the h2 tag so it adjusts the margin-top css.  Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.  Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fatfantasma/6xH5s/1/

Answer (score 47):

The bootstrap 3 docs [for horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) let you use the `.form-horizontal` class to make your form labels and inputs vertically aligned. The structure for these forms is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Label1</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Input1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input2" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Label2</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Input2">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Therefore, your form should look like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="class_type"><h2><span class=" label label-primary">Class Type</span></h2></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <select id="class_type" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off">
                <option>Economy</option>
                <option>Premium Economy</option>
                <option>Club World</option>
                <option>First Class</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your second example has the same result as mine.  I would like everything on one line and aligned properly.  Here is the jsfiddle to your example:http://jsfiddle.net/fatfantasma/6xH5s/.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: For me, what worked was to add `form-horizontal` to my `<div class="form-group">` which is probably frowned on but it worked for me! This was required for me since I was using `form-inline`. So my final solution looked like this `<div class="form-inline"><div class="form-group form-horizontal"><label/><div class="col-md-5"><input/>`

Comment: form-horizontal worked for me and saved me from adding css to individual labels and input boxes. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

When *input-lg* is used, margins mismatch unless you use *form-group-lg* in addition to *form-group* class.
Its example is in docs:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="formGroupInputLarge">Large label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="formGroupInputLarge" placeholder="Large input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="formGroupInputSmall">Small label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="formGroupInputSmall" placeholder="Small input">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 19):

None of these solutions worked for me. But I was able to get vertical centering by using `<div class="form-row align-items-center">` for each form row, per the [Bootstrap examples](https://coreui.io/docs/components/bootstrap-forms/).

Comment: This worked perfectly when nothing else seemed to work.

Comment: `<div class='form-group row align-items-center'>` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly for me in Bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="form-row align-items-center">
   <div class="col-md-2">
     <label for="FirstName" style="margin-bottom:0rem !important;">First Name</label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" class="form-control" val=""/>
  /div>
</div>
```